Magnitude of Instantaneous Velocity $=$ Instantaneous Speed Rigorous Proof
In physics, for an infinitesimal time period
$\lvert dr \rvert = ds $
Where $dr$ is displacement and $ds$ is the distance covered.
I understand this idea intuitively but am eager to know a rigorous way to prove it. I have searched both maths and physics StackExchange but can only find intuitive explanations but not rigorous ones. How can we prove this idea rigorously?
Edit 1: An analogy I can give will be that my question is similar to asking in the proof of the area of the circle why the cut-out thin strip approximates to a rectangle in the limit and not any other shape like a parallelogram. I understand the proof of the area of a circle and the idea of the thin strip becoming a rectangle in the limit intuitively but just want to know a rigorous way to show it!

Speed is defined as the magnitude of velocity.

Yeah but I am trying to get to that idea using the definition of average speed and average velocity in the limit of infinitesimal time, which requires the step that
$\lvert dr \rvert = ds$

This all comes down to how you define speed and velocity. If you define velocity using derivatives but speed using arc length, then you might find counterexamples (related to the squeeze theorem) where the velocity is finite at a point but the "speed" there is infinite or undefined.

Suppose at some initial time $t$ we have a particle whose location is described by the instantaneous position vector $\mathbf{r}(t)$. After a small time increment $\Delta t$, our particle has moved around and is now at a location described by the new position vector $\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t)$. Then we can define $\Delta\mathbf{r}$, the difference between the instantaneous position vectors, as
$$
\Delta\mathbf{r}
=\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t) -\mathbf{r}(t) 
=\langle \Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z\rangle
$$
i.e. where $\Delta\mathbf{r}$ is a small vector representing a little bit of displacement $\Delta x$ along the $\hat{x}$ direction, a little bit of displacement $\Delta y$ along the $\hat{y}$ direction, and so forth. The distance travelled by the particle in moving between $\mathbf{r}(t)$ and $\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t)$ is approximately the magnitude of $\Delta\mathbf{r}$:
$$
\Delta s \approx |\Delta\mathbf{r}|
=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2}
$$
In the limit where the time increment $\Delta t$ becomes infinitesimal; $\Delta t \rightarrow dt$, the small displacements $\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z$ also become infinitesimal, and the formula above becomes exact:
$$
ds=|d\mathbf{r}|=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}
$$
If the infinitesimal displacements are parameterised in terms of the time; i.e. $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt$ and analogously for $dy,dz$, we can write the formula for the distance travelled as
$$
ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt
=|\mathbf{v}(t)|\,dt
=v(t)\,dt
$$
where $v(t)$ is the instantaneous speed of the particle. Hence the distance travelled in a time $dt$ is the product of the speed and $dt$ itself; i.e. it is how fast the particle was going, multiplied by the time elapsed during motion, which is certainly familiar.

"The distance travelled by the particle in moving between r(t) and r(t+Δt) is approximately the magnitude of Δr". The magnitude of Δr will be the magnitude of displacement and you mean it will approximate the distance travelled in the limit. This is the part I want to explore more, is there a rigorous way to show this? I understand the idea but just want to explore the rigorous path.
